# viewDidAppear time delay issues with UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a `UIView` that I want to move to a specific position during `viewdidLoad`. Now, I know I cannot do that with `viewDidLoad` as doesn't load `UIView`, and if I am using `viewDidAppear`, a user can see the animation of the moving view.

Can someone suggest a way to achieve this? I tried to do it in the app delegate also, but I am getting a Bad Access Error:

```
LoginViewController *viewControllerss = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
viewControllerss.baseView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 20);
```

Comment: Are you using a .xib file a storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [viewDidLayoutSubview:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews) for this. This method is called after the view controller's view laid out it's subviews, so you can then make positioning decisions in your code based on the location of other views, etc.

Answer (score 0):

put this bloch in viewdidlod or viewdidappere method and set time after u wont to load your view

// Delay execution of my block for 1 seconds.

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{

(put here your code )

});